# leetcode error: raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]");

Tags: python, python-3.x

в IDE код работает хорошо, при попытке добавить на leetcode для проверки появляется ошибка:

```
    TypeError: [1, 2] is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]
    raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]");
Line 31 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 37 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Вот мой код:

```
class Solution(object):
def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
    k = []
    for num in nums:
        if num not in k:
            k.append(num)
    nums = k
    return len(nums)
```

Comment: Какое описание задачи на LeetCode?

Comment: Скорее всего нужно возвращать list а не int. ```return nums```

Comment: то, что "код работает хорошо", не означает, что код решает поставленную задачу. Код ``return a-b`` тоже работает хорошо, но для вычисления произведения двух чисел не годится. Поэтому внимательно читайте задачу, а конкретно - что именно там нужно найти.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт про [данную задачу](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/), то ошибка в том, что в вашей функции переменная `k` является списком, а должна быть целочисленным значением.
Но даже если исправить это, ответ всё равно неправильный.

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int: #  nums = [1, 1, 2]
        k = []
        for num in nums:
            if num not in k:
                k.append(num)
        nums = k # nums = [1, 1]
        k = len(nums)
        return k
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужно найти кол-во неуникальных элементов. Не особо понятно, почему во втором примере 2, в следующем 5. Вероятно, правильным ответом будет 2, но когда я возвращаю 2, то массив получается [1, 1], что тоже немного контр интуитивно.

Comment: Как я понял, нужно найти как раз таки количество уникальных элементов. а неуникальные элементы можно и не удалять из списка, главное, переместить уникальные элементы в его начало.